# with the C++ std::shared_ptr "system" is there an "official" way to extend and/or manipulate the "control block" part of a shared object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

A pointer to a good doc, paper, book, etc. on how to do this and the range of possibilities one can use would be best here.

If one can, can one add a flag or data member to such an extended control block? can one override the control block destructor? deleter? etc.

If so how, with a sample piece of code showing how would be the ultimate answer in some ways :)

Comment: We have no access to the control bock.  You could potentially derive from it, but that is fraught with its own problems.  That said, this sounds like an XY problem.  What actual problem are you trying to solve when you need to manage the control block yourself?

Comment: The control block, if it exists, is an implementation detail. There's nothing there that you can mess with.

Comment: You could make your own `peterk::shared_ptr` patterned after `std::shared_ptr`, with the enhancement that it exposes the `peterk::control_black`.

Comment: The purpose is not to mess with it, but let it do it's job, but to add something to it as it sort of operates like a "virtual base class".  The other issue is to know when it is being deleted or created,

Comment: @peterk if you want to know when something is being deleted or created write your own allocator that tags allocations. Messing with the control block isn't the right solution.

Comment: @peterk: That doesn't answer the question of why you feel you need to do that, instead of putting the information in the object itself.

Comment: This is a query about capabilities - once one knows those then one can come up with ways to use it.

That said the shared_ptr system handles multiple inheritance and all shared_ptrs have a pointer to the control block in them no matter what the pointer to the object is - this is useful in many ways.  Otherwise one has to make sure all base classes in the object have a common virtual base class and that drastically makes life difficult when using legacy code.

Comment: @peterk: "*this is useful in many ways.*" No, it is useful in *one way*: it governs the destruction of the managed object without being intrusive. That's why it exists, and that's all it does. It's not a place for you to store arbitrary stuff. Indeed, the only reason the API has to talk about it is because it requires allocations, and users should be able to control allocations. Other than that, it is *purely* an implementation detail of the object.

Comment: *this is useful in many ways*  I can see that it would be useful for development instrumentation purposes to help diagnose problems, output in log files, and maybe hook into a counter that tracks current number of objects alive, number ever created, and a high-water-mark of the most objects alive at one time.  There are other ways to do these things, but I can see that it would be useful to couple that instrumentation into the shared_ptr itself.  Is that the kind of usefulness to which you referred?

Comment: @Eljay
Is I mentioned in a comment on answer below my desire is to see what possibilities 
exist for adding features to shared_ptr and the objects they reference in such a way as to not have to re-write it. 

I am trying to convert a legacy shared_ptr system to use the std:: one because the platform and processor dependent management of atomic operations memory-blocks and reference counts, weak_ptr lists is best left to it's maintainers. The issues I have are getting the features in the legacy system to work using the std:: system in a maintainable way.

Answer (score 3):

The control block is an implementation detail of `shared_ptr`. The only access you have to it is via the interfaces that the type gives you. Which at present consists entirely of being able to decide where its storage comes from. Even if you provide an allocator to the `shared_ptr` constructor, the standard doesn't require that `shared_ptr` will even use that allocator to construct/destroy the control block object, only to allocate and free the storage for it.

Comment: Alas ...  I wish they had at least added a "user field" to it or made the deleter return a value indicating whether to destroy it or not - I am trying to convert a legacy shared_ptr system to use the std:: one because the platform and processor dependent management of atomic operations memory-blocks and reference counts, weak_ptr lists is best left to it's maintainers.   The issues I have are getting the features in the legacy system to work using the std:: system in a maintainable way.

Comment: @peterk: "*made the deleter return a value indicating whether to destroy it or not*" This is why people keep asking "what are you trying to do?" Because there's a way to do that exact thing (prevent a particular `shared_ptr<T>` chain from destroying the `T` it pretends to own). You provide a deleter object that does nothing. And if for some reason you want to have this behavior based on some state, the deleter can conditionally delete it based on said state. That state can even exist in the `T` itself.

Comment: Another question in the "relevant to this" (only shwn when creating the question) list given when I created the question was a user who wanted to recycle the control blocks for performance reasons and NOT JUST the managed object.  Which can be done if the control block is intrusive ( as managed by the shared constructor. in the "make_" methods.

Even being able to reliably determine whether the intrusive or separately allocated control block was used or not is useful.

Comment: @peterk: If I'm going to build a system where control blocks van be reused... why would I not want that system to work just as well with non-"intrusive" blocks? So the system should store allocations of different sizes, and return an allocation of the requested size (or create a new one if none are available). This would also allow sharing of control blocks between `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<U>` if `T` and `U` have the same size/alignment. So knowing whether a block is "intrusive" or not would only be useful if you unnecessarily limit yourself.

Comment: @peterk: Also, the user knows when they use `make_shared` and `allocate_shared`. You *cannot* pass an allocator to the former, and you *must* pass one to the latter. Since the user is responsible for using the *right* allocator in order to make any of this work, there is no problem here. The user simply has to provide the allocator that does block sharing. And the user won't use it when creating `shared_ptr` through non-`allocate_shared` interfaces.

Comment: "If I'm going to build a system where control blocks van be reused... "

You are absolutely right, but without reliable maintainable access to knowing when it is requested to be allocated or destroyed that can be overridden that isn't possible.

And the whole point of have a shared_ptr having two addresses one for the control block and one for the managed object is so the control block can be in a separate allocation unit(if requested )

Comment: @peterk: "*without reliable maintainable access to knowing when it is requested to be allocated or destroyed*" Did you actually *read* my answer, where I specifically said that there's an allocator that allocates and frees memory? It doesn't control object *lifetime*, but it does control *memory*, which is all that you need to do what you suggested.

Comment: And I quote you;

"Even if you provide an allocator to the shared_ptr constructor, the standard doesn't require that shared_ptr will even use that allocator to construct/destroy the control block object, only to allocate and free the storage for it."

done here :)

Comment: @peterk: Why do you need to know when the lifetime of some object is being started or ended? What you're talking about *only cares about memory*, not object lifetimes. If it frees the memory, then the lifetime of any objects in that memory have obviously ended.